# Talkback list of common issues with reading

Tags: android

I try to make my application suitable for disabled people.

Most of texts in application is dynamically retrieved from server so I'm not able to predict what content will be displayed.

Is there some list of most common reading issues relating with Talkback?

I found so far: date format, # character, 'OR' vs 'or', 'IT' vs 'it', $1,555.55 format etc. I want to have full support in my app but I cannot find at least the most popular issues.